# Swift - check if a timestamp is yesterday, today, tomorrow, or X days ago

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I'm trying to work out how to decide if a given timestamp occurs today, or +1 / -1 days. Essentially, I'd like to do something like this (Pseudocode)

```
IF days_from_today(timestamp) == -1 RETURN 'Yesterday'
ELSE IF days_from_today(timestamp) == 0 RETURN 'Today'
ELSE IF days_from_today(timestamp) == 1 RETURN 'Tomorrow'
ELSE IF days_from_today(timestamp) < 1 RETURN days_from_today(timestamp) + ' days ago'
ELSE RETURN 'In ' + days_from_today(timestamp) + ' ago'
```

Crucially though, it needs to be in Swift and I'm struggling with the NSDate / NSCalendar objects. I started with working out the time difference like this:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(timestamp))
let timeDifference = calendar.components([.Second,.Minute,.Day,.Hour],
    fromDate: date, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())
```

However comparing in this way isn't easy, because the `.Day` is different depending on the time of day and the timestamp. In PHP I'd just use mktime to create a new date, based on the start of the day (i.e. `mktime(0,0,0)`), but I'm not sure of the easiest way to do that in Swift.

Does anybody have a good idea on how to approach this? Perhaps an extension to NSDate or something similar would be best?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

`Calendar` has methods for all three cases

```
func isDateInYesterday(_ date: Date) -> Bool
func isDateInToday(_ date: Date) -> Bool
func isDateInTomorrow(_ date: Date) -> Bool
```

To calculate the days earlier than yesterday use

```
func dateComponents(_ components: Set<Calendar.Component>, 
                      from start: Date, 
                          to end: Date) -> DateComponents
```

pass `[.day]` to `components` and get the `day` property from the result.

---

This is a function which considers also `is in` for earlier and later dates by stripping the time part (Swift 3+).

```
func dayDifference(from interval : TimeInterval) -> String
{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
    if calendar.isDateInYesterday(date) { return "Yesterday" }
    else if calendar.isDateInToday(date) { return "Today" }
    else if calendar.isDateInTomorrow(date) { return "Tomorrow" }
    else {
        let startOfNow = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let startOfTimeStamp = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: startOfNow, to: startOfTimeStamp)
        let day = components.day!
        if day < 1 { return "\(-day) days ago" }
        else { return "In \(day) days" }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use `DateFormatter` for *Yesterday*, *Today* and *Tomorrow* to get localized strings for free

```
func dayDifference(from interval : TimeInterval) -> String
{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
    let startOfNow = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let startOfTimeStamp = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: startOfNow, to: startOfTimeStamp)
    let day = components.day!
    if abs(day) < 2 {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    } else if day > 1 {
        return "In \(day) days"
    } else {
        return "\(-day) days ago"
    }
}
```

Update:

In macOS 10.15 / iOS 13 [`RelativeDateTimeFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter) was introduced to return (localized) strings relative to a specific date.

Comment: Thank you! The top part looks perfect. With the bottom part, it could be 10am here, but the timestamp might be 9am tomorrow, which would give a different result to if it was 11am tomorrow. Or have I mis-understood how that works?

Comment: Great stuff, thanks again. The only change I made was the days ago line, by adding an `abs` to remove the negation, i.e. `return "\(abs(day)) days ago"`

Comment: could u help me with this question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320572/convert-timestamp-to-date-with-various-formats-swift-ios?noredirect=1#comment83626520_48320572   @vadian

Comment: Your "Best" answer requires manual calculations and checks for each case while some work could be done by iOS by default

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Which *work*? Please elaborate.

Comment: @vadian just look at my answer

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov I know but `(NS)DateFormatter` does not support *... days ago* and *In ... days* so it actually doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: @vadian I didn't mean full replacement but you could replace the part with "Yesterday", "Today" and "Tomorrow" + iOS by default adds translations for these words

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Yes you could, but you need `if - else` conditions anyway and the setup of the date formatter (date style, time style, doesRelativeDateFormatting) causes the same effort as the `Calendar` API

Comment: @vadian reread my comment - I said "some work could be done by iOS by default", *not all*. And my way allows to avoid declaring of extra constants/string literals. And finally you should at least specify that iOS may partially solve this problem

Answer (score 226):

**Swift 3/4/5:**

```
Calendar.current.isDateInToday(yourDate)
Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(yourDate)
Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(yourDate)
```

Additionally:

```
Calendar.current.isDateInWeekend(yourDate)
```

Note that for some countries weekend may be different than Saturday-Sunday, it depends on the calendar.

You can also use `autoupdatingCurrent` instead of `current` calendar, which will track user updates. You use it the same way:

```
Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.isDateInToday(yourDate)
```

`Calendar` is a type alias for the `NSCalendar`.

Comment: Omg yes! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 30):

Swift 4 update:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let date = Date()
        
calendar.isDateInYesterday(date)
calendar.isDateInToday(date)
calendar.isDateInTomorrow(date)
```

Comment: What's the point of taking the current date (`Date()`) and checking if it's yesterday or tomorrow? It looks like you wanted to change anything in a copied code...

Answer (score 11):

NSCalender has new methods that you can use directly.

```
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInTomorrow(NSDate())//Replace NSDate() with your date
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInYesterday()
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInTomorrow()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

On **Swift 5** and **iOS 13** use the RelativeDateTimeFormatter,

```
let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
formatter.dateTimeStyle = .named 

formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(day: -1)) // "yesterday"
formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(day: 1)) // "Tomorrow"
formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(hour: 2)) // "in 2 hours"
formatter.localizedString(from: DateComponents(minute: 45)) // "in 45 minutes"
```

Answer (score 2):

1)According to your example you want to receive labels "Yesterday", "Today" and etc. iOS can do this by default:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1415848-doesrelativedateformatting?language=objc

2)If you want to compute your custom label when iOS don't add these labels by itself then alternatively you can use 2 `DateFormatter` objects with both `doesRelativeDateFormatting == true` and `doesRelativeDateFormatting == false` and compare if their result date strings are the same or different