# ios - How to display date read "Today, 14 April"?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to present some dates which reads

```
Yesterday, 13 April
Today, 14 April
Tomorrow, 15 April
Tuesday, 4 April
Wednesday 5 April
```

I tried

```
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)

        let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dayFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dayFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM"
        whenLabel.text = dayFormatter.string(from: date) + ", " + dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

It is working fine as expected if the date is today, but, for other dates, I get `“Apr 5, 2017, 5 April”`

How can I get ride of this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - check if a timestamp is yesterday, today, tomorrow, or X days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345101/swift-check-if-a-timestamp-is-yesterday-today-tomorrow-or-x-days-ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two completely different formatters depending on whether the date is today or not. `doesRelativeDateFormatting` won't help you with complex formatting.

Start by checking:

```
if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) {
   // use "Today, " + "d MMMM" pattern
} else {
   // use "EEEE" pattern + "d MMMM" pattern
}
```

Comment: So for Yesterday, Today and Tomorrow one has to set it static in date formater?

Comment: @AshwinIndianic Yes because you want to have a formatter which is both relative and not relative. "Today" is usually the replacement for "14 April". That's why you need a custom solution.

Comment: Okay got your point, Thanks for helping me to improve my knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Sulthan suggest I just come to know about this kind of code,

```
let mydate = Date()//my actual date need to display
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(mydate) {
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'Today,' d MMMM"
}
else if Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(mydate) {
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'Yesterday,' d MMMM"
}
else if Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(mydate) {
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "'Tomorrow,' d MMMM"
}
else{
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, d MMMM"
 }
```

Please update me if we have any better way. Thanks

Comment: all static strings should be in quotes! e.g. `'Today,' d MMMM`

Comment: Okay thanks, (y), I was unaware about ' (single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun this is a solution which takes advantage of the localized relative date formatting.

It uses an extension of `Calendar` which determines if a date is in yesterday, today or tomorrow:

```
extension Calendar {
    func isDateInYesterdayTodayTomorrow(_ date: Date) -> Bool
    {
        return self.isDateInYesterday(date) || self.isDateInToday(date) || self.isDateInTomorrow(date)
    }
}

func relativeDateString(for date: Date, locale : Locale = Locale.current) -> String
{
    let dayFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dayFormatter.locale = locale
    if Calendar.current.isDateInYesterdayTodayTomorrow(date) {
        dayFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dayFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
    } else {
        dayFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
    }
    let relativeWeekday = dayFormatter.string(from: date)

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = locale
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM"
    return  relativeWeekday + ", " + dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```