# Convert Timestamp to Date with various formats Swift

Tags: ios, json, date, datetime, swift3

Code:-

```
let addedTime = dictMessage?.object(forKey: "added_time") as? String
let timeinterval : TimeInterval = (addedTime as NSString).doubleValu                
let dateFromServer = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:timeinterval)
let dateFormater : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()              
dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"
cellDetailsShop.lblTimeShop?.text = dateFormater.string(from: dateFromServer as Date)
```

I have a json and from json i m getting `Timestamp` which i already converted to Date.Date which i am receiving it is showing in the format `"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"`.But i want to show date like if date is of today then it will show :`Today 04:55 PM`,if date is of yesterday then i will show like: `Yesterday 5 PM` and if before that then it should show as i am retrieving from JSON. I searched various links but could not find the answer.Could someone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apple dateformatter doesnt do this. You have to do this by urself or use any framework or pod if available.

Comment: take a ref of link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345101/swift-check-if-a-timestamp-is-yesterday-today-tomorrow-or-x-days-ago

Comment: @DilipTiwari Why you begging to each developer, we are here to assist you, not to do your project, please keep in mind. Now you have enough resources are available, so it urself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from Calendar object you can get if the date is today or yesterday.
based on that you can set String as you like.
I've created an example like you need.
below is code.

```
var yesterdayStr = "17-Jan-2018 10:23 AM"
var todayStr = "18-Jan-2018 10:23 AM"
var tomorrowStr = "19-Jan-2018 10:23 AM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"
let yesterDaydate = dateFormatter.date(from: yesterdayStr)
let todayDate = dateFormatter.date(from: todayStr)
let tomorrowDate = dateFormatter.date(from: tomorrowStr)
let anotherDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
anotherDateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
if Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(yesterDaydate!)
{
    let yesterdayDisplayString = "Yesterday, " + anotherDateFormatter.string(from: yesterDaydate!)
}
if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(todayDate!) {
    let todayDisplayString = "Today, " + anotherDateFormatter.string(from: todayDate!)
}
if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(tomorrowDate!) {

}
else {
    let anotherDisplayString = anotherDateFormatter.string(from: tomorrowDate!)
}
```

and here is output, 
[image: Output of date Formatter]

Comment: date format is same as you need, so I gave you outputString which you need to set in your label. Can't you do this on your own?

Comment: I've just added 3 dates for an example to make every condition true. you just need to put core logic in your code

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
   func relativeDate(for date:Date) -> String {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .year, .month, .weekOfYear], from: date, to: Date())
        if let year = components.year, year == 1{
            return "\(year) year ago"
        }
        if let year = components.year, year > 1{
            return "\(year) years ago"
        }
        if let month = components.month, month == 1{
            return "\(month) month ago"
        }
        if let month = components.month, month > 1{
            return "\(month) months ago"
        }

        if let week = components.weekOfYear, week == 1{
            return "\(week) week ago"
        }
        if let week = components.weekOfYear, week > 1{
            return "\(week) weeks ago"
        }

        if let day = components.day{
            if day > 1{
                return "\(day) days ago"
            }else{
                "Yesterday"
            }
        }
        return "Today"
    }
```

Comment: could u change as per my code above which i m getting

Comment: You can use the above function like this         let timestamp: TimeInterval = 1515628800
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
        let formatedDate = relativeDate(for: date)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
let addedTime = dictMessage?.object(forKey: "added_time") as? String
let timeinterval : TimeInterval = (addedTime as NSString).doubleValue
let dateFromServer = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:timeinterval)
let dateFormater : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(dateFromServer) {
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "'Today' hh:mm a"
}
else if Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(dateFromServer) {
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "'Yesterday' hh:mm a"
}
else {
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a"
}
cellDetailsShop.lblTimeShop?.text = dateFormater.string(from: dateFromServer as Date)
```

Let me know if you have any comment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it without a custom date format `DateFormatter` provides localized relative formatting. The date format considers the settings in System Preferences.

```
let dateFromServer = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -100000)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
let string = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromServer)
```

---

Please don't use  Foundation `NSString` and `NSDate` in Swift, use the native structs

```
if let addedTime = dictMessage?["added_time"] as? String,
    let timeinterval = TimeInterval(addedTime) {
        let dateFromServer = Date(timeIntervalSince1970:timeinterval)
        let dateFormater = DateFormatter() 
        ...
}
```